# create random data with certain degree of spatial autocorrelation

Tags: python, matrix, pysal

I need to create a random 1000x1000 matrix with certain degree of spatial autocorrelation. I have found a python library [pysal](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/darribas/9943372), but the process need creating a 1000000x1000000 matrix, which makes the program crashing. Is there any way solving this problem? Does the sparse matrix make any sense? Any one who has alternative solution will be appreciated a lot.